# What are the options for developing powerful browser hosted UI in Java?

Tags: java, silverlight

I am interested to widen my horizons and wish to learn what are the options for developing a powerful browser hosted UI in Java. All I know is .NET based solutions, specifically Silverlight, which I find extremely powerful, although not without some regretful omissions as compared to its elder brother - WPF.

So, to rephrase my question. Are there **mature** Silverlight alternatives in Java?

Thanks.

P.S.

- I am not starting the war of Java vs .NET, so please do not raise the benefits of Java against .NET in general. I am interested in a specific area only, anything else is put aside.
- Please, do not bring Adobe AIR, flex, HTML5, etc... The questions is about Java.

Comment: Flex with Java? http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex_java.html

Comment: JavaFX is the "Silverlight alternative" if you're going for "pure Java" - however, in practice JavaFX is rarely used (for a variety of reasons).  I'd argue that in practice, if you're going for a RIA in Java-land, the combination of a Flex front-end with a Java back-end is much more common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is about Java, but front-ends for the web are almost never written in pure Java.

- [GWT](https://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) - that's where you write pure Java which is then translated to javascript and html automatically
- [JSF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/javaserverfaces-139869.html) - you reuse rich components to create your pages. Still there's html and javascript. This resembles the ASP.NET model
- [Vaadin](http://vaadin.com/home) - heard of it, never used it. Seems promising
- [ZK](http://www.zkoss.org/) - Same as above.
- jQuery - yes, this has nothing to do with Java, but is very powerful tool for creating rich UI
- Flex - easy integration with Java back-ends. (I personally don't like Flex, but it's a viable option)

(I specifically omitted JavaFX, because in my opinion it is not yet mature)

Answer (score 2):

You know, having rich applications in the browser using Java has existed since, say, 1999 : applets, that's what they're for.
They were long far from beautiful. However, with the recent apparition of JavaFX, they can now have a very nice look.

Comment: I know about applets and I agree about "long far from beautiful". That is the "powerful" and "rich" part of Silverlight, that I am looking in java. But JavaFX is new for me. I do not know is that is the answer, but +1 it deserves.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing to Silverlight in the Java world is [JavaFX](http://javafx.com/). I haven't worked with it myself though, and I don't think I've randomly come across any sites using it in the wild... which means your users are less likely to have whatever plugin is required... and you're likely to be cutting out most mobile users too. (I believe there's a mobile flavour of JavaFX, or at least one planned, but you really want to find out whether it exists on iPhone/Android/(whatever your target market is).

Personally I would probably try to stick to HTML 5 and JavaScript, which can still be pretty rich. (That doesn't necessarily mean writing all the UI by hand, of course - projects like GWT and jQuery are your friends.)

Answer (score 1):

[Open Laszlo](http://www.openlaszlo.org/) is worth a look they have a nice interactive [demo](http://www.openlaszlo.org/lps_demos/laszlo-explorer/index.html?lzr=dhtml?navset=nav10.xml&bookmark=Introduction#_lzbookmark=Laszlo%20in%2010%20Minutes) section too.

The [OpenLaszlo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenLaszlo) platform consists of the LZX programming language and the OpenLaszlo Server:

- LZX is an XML and JavaScript description language similar in spirit to XUL, MXML, and XAML. LZX enables a declarative, text-based development process that supports rapid prototyping and software development best practices. It is designed to be familiar to traditional web application developers who are familiar with HTML and Javascript.
- The OpenLaszlo Server is a Java servlet that compiles LZX applications into executable binaries for targeted run-time environments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it fits your demand but have you looked at the Google Web Toolkit? It compiles Java to javascript and some colleges have made nice UI's with it.

Answer (score 0):

I've used GWT before and more recently [Vaadin](http://vaadin.com/home) which I would recommend. You can give it a go at a demo sampler [here](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler). I am currently using it to create custom portlets for the [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/) CMS/Portal and I am pretty happy with it.